# У всех пользователей android studio debug key одинаковый?

Tags: android-studio

Спрашиваю об этом , потому что создал приложение в вк , туда прописал отпечаток дебаг ключа андроид студио. И выложил код на github , если кто то подпишет приложение другим ключом, то при использовании функций вк получит ошибку. Поэтому мне интересно знать у всех ли кто использует студию дебаг ключ один и тот же. Вроде как название одно и пароль  один: android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разный. К тому же, [время жизни у него 365 дней](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#expdebug). Можете сравнить SHA-1 ключей с разных машин, чтоб убедиться.

Comment: Если студия сгенерировала ключ, то через год он студия будет пытаться подписать уже ключом с истекшим сроком и будет получать ошибку ? (ясно что для этого надо удалить ключ и она сгенерирует новый)   А приложение подписанное этим ключом установится на телефон через год ? А уже установленное приложение через год продолжит работать ?  Вот такие вопросики по теме еще возникли)

Comment: @Turalllb а зачем вы собираете релизную версию приложения с дебаг ключом? Вы с дебаг ключом даже не сможете залить .apk в гугл стор.

Comment: Что касается других вопросов. Да, при билде будет ошибка. Нет, приложение с истёкшим ключём не получится установить. Да, приложение, которое УЖЕ установлено, будет работать.

Comment: Suvitruf, не собираюсь делать релиз используя дебаг ключ. Просто любопытно.